# If $x_n$ and $y_n$ are sequences where $x$ converges to a value other than $0$ and $x_ny_n$ converges, then $y_n$ converges.

Tags: real-analysis

Does this make sense?

Since $x_n$ converges to a value other than $0$, and $x_ny_n$ converges, then:

$$y_n = \frac{x_ny_n}{x_n}$$ also converges.

Comment: If X and Y are sequences, XY makes no sense.

Comment: @JonMarkPerry I edited the question so it made more sense.

Answer (score 0):

That argument works, but you need to show the details. For example, suppose $x_n\to x\ne0$ and $x_ny_n\to z$. Choose $N$ large enough that $|x_n|>0$ for $n>N$. Then if $n>N$, 
$$\left|y_n-\frac zx\right| = \left|\frac{x_ny_n}{x_n}-\frac zx \right|.$$
The result follows from the fact that $a_n\to a$, $b_n\to b\ne 0$ implies $$\frac{a_n}{b_n}\to \frac ab.$$